# Listing Cities A custom taxonmy by selection order

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, sort

I have below code that lists cities in ascending order, I want to lists cities based on the order I select the cities from the frontend. It is a shortcode created by theme. Cities is a custom taxonomy here.

How should I do this please advise?

Screenshot of City Listing in ASC order: https://prnt.sc/s87to8 backend city selection https://prnt.sc/s87gyi

**view.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('FW')){
    die('Forbidden');
}
/**
 * @var $atts
 */

$title              = !empty( $atts['title'] ) ? $atts['title'] : '';
$description        = !empty( $atts['description'] ) ? $atts['description'] : '';
$cities             = !empty( $atts['city'] ) ? $atts['city'] : array();
$city_buttons       = !empty( $atts['city_buttons'] ) ? $atts['city_buttons'] : array();

?>
<?php if ( !empty( $cities ) ) { ?>
        <div class="tg-popularcities">                  
        <?php 
            $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'cities',
                'include'       => $cities,
                'hide_empty'    => 0
            ) );

            if ( !empty( $terms ) ){                            
                foreach ( $terms as $key => $value ) {
                    $country_name = '';                  
                    $get_cities_meta = fw_get_db_term_option( $value->term_id, 'countries' );
                    if (!empty($get_cities_meta['country'][0])) {
                        $country_id = $get_cities_meta['country'][0];
                        $country_term = get_term($country_id, 'countries');
                        $country_name = $country_term->slug;                                                  
                    }

                    $city_name = $value->slug;  
                    $custom_url = "?country=".$country_name."&city=".$city_name;                            
                    $term_data = fw_get_db_term_option( $value->term_id, 'cities' );                        
                    $cat_image = !empty( $term_data['image']['url'] ) ? $term_data['image']['url'] : get_template_directory_uri().'/images/locations/city.jpg';
                    $total_users    = listingo_get_total_users_under_taxanomy($city_name,'number','city');
                ?>                                      
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="tg-topcity">
                        <figure class="tg-cityimg">                                 
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $cat_image ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_html_e('City Image', 'listingo'); ?>">                                   
                            <figcaption>                                        
                                <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $value->term_id, 'cities' ) ); echo esc_attr( $custom_url  ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $value->name ); ?></a></h3>
                                <span><?php echo esc_attr( $total_users ); ?>&nbsp;<?php esc_html_e('Listings', 'listingo'); ?></span>                                      
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

**options.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('FW'))
    die('Forbidden');

$options = array(
    'title' => array(
        'label' => esc_html__('Heading', 'listingo'),
        'desc' => esc_html__('Add section heading. leave it empty to hide.', 'listingo'),
        'type' => 'text',
    ),
    'description' => array(
        'type' => 'wp-editor',
        'label' => esc_html__('Description', 'listingo'),
        'desc' => esc_html__('Add section description. leave it empty to hide.', 'listingo'),
        'tinymce' => true,
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'teeny' => true,
        'wpautop' => false,
        'editor_css' => '',
        'reinit' => true,
        'size' => 'small', // small | large
        'editor_type' => 'tinymce',
        'editor_height' => 200
    ),
    'city' => array(
        'type' => 'multi-select',
        'label' => esc_html__('Select Cities', 'listingo'),
        'population' => 'taxonomy',
        'source' => 'cities',
        'prepopulate' => 500,
        'desc' => esc_html__('Show cities as per your selection. Leave it empty to show from all.', 'listingo'),
    ),
    'city_buttons' => array(
        'type' => 'addable-box',
        'label' => esc_html__('Add Button', 'listingo'),
        'desc' => esc_html__('', 'listingo'),
        'box-options' => array(
            'button_text' => array('type' => 'text'),
            'button_link' => array('type' => 'text'),
        ),
        'template' => '{{- button_text }}', // box title
        'box-controls' => array(// buttons next to (x) remove box button
            'control-id' => '<small class = "dashicons dashicons-smiley"></small>',
        ),
        'limit' => 1, // limit the number of boxes that can be added
        'add-button-text' => esc_html__('Add', 'listingo'),
        'sortable' => true,
    ),
);
```

Comment: Anyone can assist me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding 'orderby'  => 'term_order', line solved this issue.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'cities',
                    'include'       => $cities,
                    'orderby'  => 'term_order',
                    'order'    => 'ASC',
                    'hide_empty'    => 0
                ) );
```